# Sort only particular index in python with corresponding pair

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list which contains the following

```
a= [june,32,may,67,april,1,dec,99]
```

I want to sort only the numbers in descending order
but it should display with corresponding pair:

```
Output Expected
----------------
dec,99,may,67,june,32,april,1
```

I tried to sort using `a.sort(reverse=True)` command in the list not getting the expected output,this one is confusing a lot.

Comment: 01 is invalid in Python3 (it's old 2.7 octal notation). strings need to be quoted

Comment: @tonypdmtr edited Thanks.!!

Comment: (you missed the 2nd part) ... strings need to be quoted: `a = ['june',32,'may',67,'april',1,'dec',99]`

Comment: `a = [x for s in [[b,a] for a,b in sorted([(a[i],a[i-1]) for i in range(len(a)) if i%2 == 1],reverse=True)] for x in s]`

Answer (score 5):

You can use a list of tuples:

```
a = ['june', '32', 'may', '67', 'april', '01', 'dec', '99']

zipper = zip(a[::2], a[1::2])

res = sorted(zipper, key=lambda x: -int(x[1]))  # or, int(x[1]) with reverse=True

print(res)

[('dec', '99'), ('may', '67'), ('june', '32'), ('april', '01')]
```

If you need to flatten, use `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain

res = list(chain.from_iterable(res))

['dec', '99', 'may', '67', 'june', '32', 'april', '01']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first create nested lists containing the month-value pair, apply `sorted`, and then flatten:

```
a= ['june',32,'may',67,'april',01,'dec',99]
new_a = sorted([[a[i], a[i+1]] for i in range(0, len(a), 2)], key=lambda x:x[-1], reverse=True)
final_a = [i for b in new_a for i in b]
```

Output:

```
['dec', 99, 'may', 67, 'june', 32, 'april', 1]
```